# Mock object not recognized as Mockito in Flutter widget test using GetIt

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, widget-test-flutter, mockito-dart

I am writing a widget test that verifies a logout button. When the logout function is triggered via a user button tap, some items in FlutterSecureStorage are cleared. I want to verify that a method was called in our Preferences class which is a wrapper for FlutterSecureStorage. We use GetIt as a dependency injector in the app and for tests.

In my widget test, I have declared a Mock for our Preferences class as follows:

```
class MockPreferences extends Mock implements IPreferences {
  @override
  Future<void> clearPreferences() async {
    // clear some values
  }
}
```

In my widget test setup I have the following:

```
GetIt.instance.registerSingleton<IPreferences>(MockPreferences());
```

And in my testWidgets I am obtaining a reference to the mock as follows:

```
var prefs = GetIt.instance<IPreferences>();
```

When my widget test runs, when I place a break point after the line above, I can verify that the `prefs` object is definitely of type `MockPreferences` and other interactions with the widget test prove that methods are being called on the mock object and not the real object.

When I try to verify that the `clearPreferences()` method was called using Mockito's `verify` function as follows:

```
  var prefs = GetIt.instance<IPreferences>();
  verify(prefs.clearPreferences()).called(greaterThan(0));

The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test: Used a non-mockito object.
```

Placing a breakpoint after the `var prefs` line I can see the the prefs object IS a mockito object, but the test will not recognize it as a mockito object and the test fails.

Can anyone offer any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: Are you using more than one mocking testing lib in your project? Such as Mocktail and Mockito. That was the main reason of the issue.

Comment: I have also encountered this problem and I wasn't using more than one mocking testing library